# When is Application_BeginRequest invoked in parent site

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this senario where my site www.skinb5.com should redirect to www.skinb5.com/au/

and www.skinb5.com/au should directly go to the www.skinb5.com/au and  www.skinb5.com/us

should go to www.skinb5.com/us.

www.skinb5.com is a parent site which pretty much does nothin but to redirect.  /au/ and /us/ are child sites sitting under it.

Please have a look at my Global.asax file in my parent site where the only redirect happens.

The problem is when i go  www.skinb5.com/us/ it returns 200 which is good. But

www.skinb5.com/au/ it returns 302 to www.skinb5.com/au/. Though it doesn't go in an infinite loop, I am concerned why it returns 302.

you might want to test here at http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/

**My questions is, when I invoke www.skinb5.com/au/ directly,  will the application_beginRequest in parentsite be invoked? Shouldn't it directly go to the child site? If so how does the 302 redirect happen.**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var redirectSite = "au";
        HttpCookie languageCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("Customer.SelectLanguageID");
        if (languageCookie != null)
        {
            redirectSite = languageCookie.Value.Split('-')[1];

        }

        string rawUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawUrl))
        {
            rawUrl = "/";
        }

        rawUrl = redirectSite + rawUrl;
        bool useSsl = IsCurrentConnectionSecured();
        var storeHost = GetStoreHost(useSsl);
        if (storeHost.EndsWith("/"))
            storeHost = storeHost.Substring(0, storeHost.Length - 1);
        string url = storeHost + '/' + rawUrl;
        url = url.ToLowerInvariant();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, true);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A redirect tells the browser to load a different URL. The browser does this just as though the new URL was typed in the address bar. It is a request like any other.

So all requests and redirects will cause `Application_BeginRequest()` to fire.

If you don't want it to do anything on the redirected request, you'll need to test the target URL and decide if any action is to be taken.